# How to respond to Home Clicks Android

Tags: java, android, api, service

I'd like to create an app that responds to home clicks (double-tap home clicks) and then can launch an app. I need the app to be constantly on, so I understand that I need it as a service... but I have not found a way to respond to home clicks and read/recognize them, is there any possible way that there is something like this in the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The home-button is supposed to open the (a) launcher. You can define your app to be a launcher by Intent-Filter in the Android Manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The negative impact is that it always opens your app if you push the home button.

Comment: I understand this, but I'm not sure how to call it then... I want my app to set the phone to open Google when the home button is pressed twice... not my app to be opened. Thanks for the response.